# Flutter: Concurrent modification during iteration

Tags: flutter, dart

So I know that my mistake lies in trying to change my data when im iterating through it

this is the exact error

> "Expected Non-error `Concurrent modification during iteration:
> Instance of 'LinkedMap<dynamic, dynamic>'.

and this is my code:

```
  _products.forEach((key, value) {
    if (key.titel == product.titel) {
      _products[key] += 1;
    } else {
      _products[product] = 1;
    }
  }
```

but I don't really get how I would be able to modify my data without iterating through it. Any suggestions?

----------------my Attempt -------------------

```
  var _products = {}.obs;
  var temp = {}.obs;

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    temp = _products;
    if (_products.length > 0) {
      _products.forEach((key, value) {
        if (key.titel == product.titel) {
          temp[key] += 1;
        } else {
          temp[product] = 1;
        }
      });
    }
```

I get the same error; I think that is because in this line:

```
temp = _products;
```

I just get the reference on _products & I don't write _products in temp

Comment: Create a new map that contains the updated state, and assign `_products` to it.

Comment: thank you! Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can mark this question as solved?

Comment: Its really more suited as a comment than a proper answer. If you figured it out then I suggest posting an answer yourself with the code you wrote to solve this.

Comment: @mmcdon20 I think that doesn't work, because you just have the reference and don't create a new object; I ll show you my attempt in the question

Comment: The issue with your attempt is that you are not creating a new map, you are setting `temp = _products`, and so you are still modifying the same instance that you are iterating over. You could try setting `temp` to a copy of `_products` like `temp = {..._products}`.

Comment: I did it by saying 
    temp = RxMap<dynamic, dynamic>.from(_products);

that fixed the initial problem, but I still have something really weird going on

Comment: Weird in what way?

Comment: I misused the .forEach iterator & therefore I had a weird misbehaviour, it has nothing to do with the question, it would waste too much of your time to explain ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mmcdon suggested you need make a copy of your existing thing that you want to iterate upon & iterate through that instead of your original piece

So in my case I need to do this:

```
  var _products = {}.obs;
  var temp = {}.obs;

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    temp = RxMap<dynamic, dynamic>.from(_products);
    if (_products.length > 0) {
      temp.forEach((key, value) {
        if (key.titel == product.titel) {
          _products[key] += 1;
        } else {
          _products[product] = 1;
        }
      });
    }
```

So as you can see I iterate through temp, that basically is _products & Im writing the data that I need in _products